# Is there a c++(MFC) database object that can execute multiple SQL statements(as in a script) in one instruction?

Tags: c++, mfc

Is there a c++(preferably MFC) database object that can execute multiple SQL statements(as in a script) in one instruction? Like this :

```
DatabaseObject.RunSQL("Insert into GN_Version values (1,2,3,4); Insert into GN_Version values (5,2,3,4); Insert into GN_Version values (3,2,3,4);");
```

Comment: Maybe create a stored procedure, and then execute that from MFC?

Comment: Not an option, I use either sql server, acces or oracle databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, I found that with the SQL Server ODBC Driver, [`CDatabase.ExecuteSQL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67cze9b7.aspx) can execute multiple statements in one instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Have worked with MFC together with SQL Server for several years. Have never encountered such a function. Usually, there is some tokenizer involved to accomplish that.

As a comparison, [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) does support such multi-statements through its APIs.